# Ember data retrieve multiple instances of the same model in one route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I currently have an ember app that's trying to retrieve data from a 3rd party API using Ember Data. The urls are in the format, /user_id/date/food, which would retrieve the user's consumed food on the given day. I want to retrieve the list of foods the user consumed given a date range (2015-06-07, 2015-08-10).

I tried to use Ember.query and filter out the unnecessary data, but the API doesn't have an endpoint which would return all of the consumed foods.

Currently I'm supporting the single day query using queryRecord and passing the day in.

Comment: Can you specify what your actual question is? Do you have any code to show that didn't work? Examples of the data you're receiving, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `/user_id/date/food` is the only endpoint the 3rd party API is providing, the only option you would have is to make a request for every day in the range you want to get. You might want to use `Ember.RSVP.all` to wait till all requests are retrieved and finally concatenate the result for example.

But this is not really recommended, because a large range would be very inefficient.